# How to use Google Nearby Messages API in a cordova app

Tags: cordova, google-nearby

Is it possible to use Google's Nearby Messages API (https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview) in a Cordova app? And if yes then how?

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this

1) Search for any cordova plugin if there is any to achieve your requirement

2) Create your own plugin to get your requirement done. You can get started on how to create a cordova plugin here (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/)

Note : **Whatever is there in native android API that can be achieved in cordova by creating plugins**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There is a cordova plug (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-google-nearby)

But I also think it is better to create your own plugin to get your requirement done.